# Is this design a service locator design pattern?

Tags: c++, architecture, design-patterns

I was reading what a service locator pattern is from [this article](http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/service-locator.html), and now I'm just wondering if I merge service and locator classes is it still a service locator pattern or not? And if not, do you think this implementation is usable enough as single or service locator pattern? (since the example was an audio manager I'll give same example here)

```
class IAudio{
private:
    static IAudio* instance;
    static IAudio _NULLINSTANCE;        
public:
    IAudio()
    {
        instance = &NULLINSTANCE;
    }

    IAudio* getInstance() 
    {
        return instance;
    };

    void registerInstance(IAudio* pInstance) 
    {
        instance = pInstance;
    }

    virtual void load(const char* path) 
    { 
        //do nothing
    }

    virtual void play(const char* path) 
    { 
        //do nothing
    }

    virtual void stop(const char* path) 
    { 
        //do nothing
    }
};
```

And then I'll inherit classes I need from AudioManager and call registerInstance in my initialization function.

Comment: Why the `char*`? At least `const` it, if not even `const std::string&`.

Comment: Using a const char * rather than a const string & can do wonders to prevent memory fragmentation and allocator contention, especially on C++ standard libraries that don't use the small string optimization.

Comment: please don't be too hard on just an example.

Comment: why all downvote? it's a design that is usualy can used in games!

Comment: Fair question, here are my downvote resons: I for one don't see a need (and never had one in any project) for different AudioManagers and an AudioManager inheritance tree. Your code makes this assumption. 
Besides, there will be code that creates those different AudioManagers and _manages_ them, they are created outside this class, so there is another audio _managing_ code beside the actual AudioManager, that would be the **AudioManagerManager**.

Comment: @maik: I think i can defend my question: first of all AudioManager is just an example and as i mention I picked AudioManager to keep similarity to the article which introduced this pattern. and second as that article gave example you can have 2 diffrent audio managers one for debug program and one for release, and just decide in compiletime which one do you want to use. or for diffrent platforms you can have different audioManager classes. it's all some compile time states and not a real managing thing. and my code is introducing a wrapper for all those diffrent implementations of audiomanager

Comment: I know @Gajet, as I said, I don't see a need for different AudioManagers.

Comment: I am downvoting because you're putting too much belief into the idea of design patterns. Go with a logical design, rather than fit it into a pattern. It's like your problem is a splat shape, and you're trying to fit it into a square hole.

Comment: @TheCommunistDuck: the whole idea of design pattern itself is worth nothing to me! but the important thing to be able to satisfy your team why did you use this specific design, and for them knowing that it's a known design and it's used before makes pattern much more acceptable. on the other hand just seeing some design is categorised as an antiPattern gives them absolute certain that design should be changed even if the distadvantages of that antipattern is not applied in your design. I just want to have a refrence that some people accepted my idea before implementing it.

Comment: @Gajet If the whole idea of design patterns were nothing to you, then this question is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @Gajet just because a design is a known pattern, doesn't make it a good choice for each and every programming situation. If that alone convinces a team I'd say, I'd try to find another ;) Now seriously: try to ignore patterns for a while, explain to your team why, if it happens that your design is also a known pattern, then so be it, but don't force it :)

Comment: @maik: after the last attemp I gave up convining my team, it was around a year ago and I was developing baseclasses for and adventure game, after around 6 mounths when almost all the classes were ready to use, they started complaining it's hard to code in this situation why didn't you use standard pattern and so on . that's why i'm asking this question here, and I think my first choice for using this pattern is as a game director (I mean this class is a base state class and also has a pointer to active state).

Comment: @Gajet sounds like something needs to be fixed in your team's communication, rather than in the code ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is no longer the service locator pattern because anything that would like to talk to the audio service, now has to know about the class, it's location/package etc..

Take a good look at this quote from the site you linked:

> These callsites, of course, have to be
>   coupled to something in order to make
>   a sound play, but letting them poke
>   directly at the concrete audio
>   implementation is like giving a
>   hundred strangers directions to your
>   house just so they can drop a letter
>   on your doorstep. Not only is it a
>   little bit too personal, it’s a real
>   pain when you move and you have to
>   tell each person the new directions.

In the final example any game object that can ask for the audio engine only has to know about the IAudio interface and where the locator is. Not where the actual AudioService class is. By putting the locator inside the AudioService you violate this idea, and you just get a weird singleton.

Comment: it's defenetly not a singleton since there is function `registerInstance` and by the way any one can see both IAudio and locator services. so didn't reveal any information about how `ConsoleAudio` is implemented. as i comment for communistduck my interface doesn't do anything at all, it's just representing as NULLAudio class as well as others.

Answer (score 3):

First off, this is not gamedev related and as such is a more SO question. Also, why should it matter if you're using the service locator pattern? Why should it matter if your code is an observer, or a visitor? Design patterns are meant as structures that can be used for generic aim. It is unlikely you will need them in their raw form.

Anyway, it is not. The idea of a service pattern is to act as a messenger. You, person `X`, want to get an object `Z`. The service provider `Y` simply has a reference to `Z`, and passes you that. The idea is that you do not need to know anything about `Z` (other than what it is). It could be a red object, a blue object, a yellow object - the service provider is simply giving you the object without having to reference it exactly.

In this case, the load/play/stop functions are just showing this as a singleton. You want three classes; an interface `IAudio` which is what you program against, a `AudioServiceProvider` which has the `IAudio` pointer, and a number of `Audio` concrete classes that implement `IAudio`. You have missed out the middle step.

Comment: In my example the middle part is not forgotten, usually there has to be a number of audio concrete classes that Implement IAudio, it's only baseclass is also the NULL class. in that article there were 4 classes introduced : `IAudio`, `ConsoleAudio`, `Locator`, and `NullAudio`. The only thing I've done was mergeing Locator with IAudio and NullAudio to just orginise my code a little bit. and I'm asking cause i don't want to endup with some antipaterns inside my code.

Comment: @Gajet The fact you are using singletons indicates antipatterns don't seem to worry you.

Comment: @TheCommunistDuck : singletons aren't antipatterns, or at least as I read about that pattern in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) it's categorised as a pattern! and I myself didn't ever use them in the past conversations I just mentions it's widly used in many GameEngines. at the end I said i use global pointers myself.

Comment: @Gajet Singletons are widely regarded as an anti-pattern, since they are used widely even though their actual use case is tiny. And Wikipedia isn't always right.

Comment: @TheCommunistDuck : in the end do you think it has not enough in common with locator pattern to call so? and do you think it's somthing not usable or does it has it's own usecases?

Comment: @Gajet The locator pattern is not a singleton. It's more of a global - it may only hold one instance of the service itself, but the locator has no need to be a singleton.

Comment: Actually [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) mentions that "some consider it an Anti-Pattern"

Comment: @TheCommunist Duck: the only reason that locator pattern is ***not*** a singleton is because you can create mutiple instances from every object that inherit IAudio class. so the approch I've sugested is more like a locator to a singleton.